# Rewrite condition to use only one console.log

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
movies = [1,2,3,4,5];
watchedMovies = [1,2,3];
const buttonPressed= false;

movies.map(item => buttonPressed === true ? !watchedMovies.includes(item) && 
console.log(item) : console.log(item))
```

How can I rethink this to use only one "console.log". I have a button in my react app that if I press will hide my watched movies and the "console.log" is actually a "JSX" element with all the logic here so will be hard for me to transform it into a component so I don't reuse code.

Comment: You can't use the return value of `console.log()`, it's a void method and therefore returns `undefined`

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: What's the purpose of `console.log` here anyway?

Comment: if you press the hideWatchedMoviesButton and buttonPressed is true show only movies that I didn't watch else show all the movies. This is simplified for example sake. The console.log is actualy a JSX element made from the movie object and I don't want to write it two times.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. Though **.map** iterator has curly braces to mark as a function block, but take note map needs to **return** a value. E.g.
`movies.map(item => { console.log(item); if(buttonPressed) { console.log('buttonPressed'); return item;} });`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-pond-2sys7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You mean `{movies.map((item, i) =>(filtWatched === false || !watchedMovies.includes(item)) ? <li key={item}>{item}</li>:<React.Fragment key={i}></React.Fragment>)}`? The <></> means return react.fragment or empty.

Comment: wow, that's amazing thank you @Han

Answer (score 1):

Based on your own answer, I think what you actually want is a filter:

```
let visibleMovies = movies;
if (!buttonPressed) {
    visibleMovies = visibleMovies.filter(item => !watchedMovies.includes(item))
}

// ...

visibleMovies.map(item => /*make JSX element*/)
```

Comment: !buttonPressed && movies.filter(item => !watchedMovies.includes(item)).map(item => console.log(item)) this will have a filter, a include and a map as opposed to to a map and a incluse. So more calculation.

Comment: It's still `O(n)`, so it's not a big deal. How many elements are we taking about? If it's somewhere between 1 and 10000 then we don't even have to talk about it. Computers are fast. Maintainability of code is more important than a constant factor change in runtime performance (most of the time at least).

Answer (score 0):

```
movies.map(item => (buttonPressed === true || !watchedMovies.includes(item)) &&
console.log(item))
```